# How to declare a class with a parameter type of T when T will be null?

Tags: c#, .net

So I have this class:

```
    public class MyCallResponse<T>
    {
        public bool Success{ get; set; }
        public T Result { get; set; }
        // others
    }
```

This class gets used for many different call types. Thus the `T` for `Result`. BUT... when coding, I always know ahead of time what type `T` will be. So I can use it like this:

```
MyCallResponse<List<foo>> response = await MakeACall<List<foo>>();
```

or

```
MyCallResponse<int> response = await MakeACall<int>();
```

or

```
MyCallResponse<string> response = await MakeACall<string>();
```

And then I have the method:

```
public async Task<MyCallResponse<T>> MakeACall<T>()
{
}
```

Works great!

But, what I can't figure out is how to use this when I *know* that the return type will be `null`.  This doesn't work:

```
MyCallResponse<null> response = await MakeACall<null>();
```

> Using the generic type 'MyCallResponse' requires 1 type arguments

Not to mention c# also doesn't know what to do with `MakeACall<null>()`

Some other posts keep saying to use `default(T)` but I'm not sure how to use that in my context.

Ideas?  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Based on the comment by Igor, I solved the first half of my problem like this:

```
public class MyCallResponse
{
    public bool Success{ get; set; }
    // others
}

public class MyCallResponse<T> : MyCallResponse
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can do this:

```
APICallResponse<string> response = ...
```

Or

```
APICallResponse response = ...
```

What I'm working on now is this:

```
APICallResponse response = await MakeACall<???>();
```

When I don't need a type passed in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204149/discussion-between-madreflection-and-casey-crookston).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null is not a type in C#. And a generic type has to have a type argument. If you want to use `APICallResponse` rather than `APICallResponse<T>` than you must declare another type/class with name APICallResponse.